# Rebuild Texlipse project on modified file which is not *.tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlipse

Usually, texlipse starts rebuilding my project when i save a modified `*.tex` file. I have several figures created with `tikz` that are stored as `*.tikz` files that I often modify. In this case I do not get an updated version of my document. So I have to go to any `*.tex` file, modify and save it, which then starts a rebuild of the whole project.

Can I somehow add custom file extensions to the build process?